# Android FrameLayout Views Overlapping not Working

Tags: android, android-layout

I Have the following layout and I need the favorite image to placed on the upper right corner of the itemImage using FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemDetails"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemdimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:elevation="10dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>
```

But the favorite image is never show ??  what is wrong with my layout

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The layout seems ok for me, the image is on the top right corner in my Android Studio. Maybe the problem is when you change the image programmatically.

Comment: @RomainGoutte-Fangeas I change nothing in Activity code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this layout will work. I changed `tools:srcCompat` to `android:src`. `tools:` attributes are only visible in AndroidStudio, they are removed from the build.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemdimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The result is this :

[image: layout display result]